# Using waxjs to get information about NFTs in Wax Cloud Wallet - possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, blockchain, atomicassets

I'm trying right now to integrate the Wax Cloud Wallet into my React/NextJS App.

For that, I'm using [waxjs](https://github.com/worldwide-asset-exchange/waxjs) and the documentation [here](https://developer.wax.io/en/wax-cloud-wallet/waxjs/waxjs_use.html).

Right now, the User can log in to his account and the app receives the account name and two public keys. But I have no Idea how I then use that information to check which kind of NFTs are in the wallet, or if there are specific ones.

Is that with waxjs even possible, or do I have to use a different one?

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import * as waxjs from '@waxio/waxjs/dist'

const Wallet = () => {
  const [userAccount, setUserAccount] = useState('No Wallet Linked')
  const [pubKeys, setPubKeys] = useState('No Public Keys')
  var wax
  useEffect(() => {
    wax = new waxjs.WaxJS({
      rpcEndpoint: 'https://wax.greymass.com',
    })
    console.log('Started Wax:', wax)
  }, [])

  async function login() {
    try {
      const user = await wax.login()
      const publicKeys = wax.pubKeys
      console.log(pubKeys)
      console.log(wax)
      setUserAccount(user)
      setPubKeys(publicKeys)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('User failed to login: ', error)
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-10 text-center">
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold">Wallet</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => login()}
        className="bg-orange text-black text-3xl px-4 py-2"
      >
        Login
      </button>
      <h4 className="font-semibold">{userAccount}</h4>
      <h5>{pubKeys}</h5>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Wallet
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use is this: https://wax.api.atomicassets.io/docs/ You can get to this link by visiting AtomicHub marketplace (if you're familiar) and going to 'API' at the bottom of the page.

And specifically it seems you want to use the following API:

```
https://wax.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/assets?owner={account name}
```

You would still use waxjs along with this, to login the user and get his {account name} for the query above. You could then use the 'api' object in waxjs to do transactions. You can read more about that object here: [https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosjs/latest/API-Reference/classes/*eosjs_api*.api](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosjs/latest/API-Reference/classes/_eosjs_api_.api)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's quite easy. Once you have the user's wallet address, make a call to the ExplorerApi like this:

```
const { ExplorerApi } = require('atomicassets');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

console.log('loading nft asset_ids for wallet ' + userAccount + '...');
const api = new ExplorerApi("https://wax.api.atomicassets.io", "atomicassets", {fetch});
let assets : IAsset[] = await api.getAssets({owner: userAccount});
console.log(assets);
```

and remember in package.json:

```
"atomicassets": "^1.4.2",
```

There you go! Good luck ;)

Comment: Thank you, I actually made the call with my Laravel api in the end.